# vscode debug console is blank running my Javascript program on my Windows desktop, but a message top right says 'showing 0 of 12'. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode-debugger

I'm running a Javascript program in vscode.  It runs on my Windows laptop and produces output in the Debug console, but when I switch to my Windows desktop and run it, there is no output in the debug console, and the messages '0 closed' and 'Showing 0 of [somenumber]'appears at the top.  How do I fix it?

I had previously been using Python in vscode on the desktop (may or may not be relevant). I tried disabling Anconda.

I deleted the launch.json file and created it again with the default Launch program for Node.
No change.  My program runs but no output in the debug console.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by deleting \Code and .vscode from my PC

The folder locations on windows are in the path locations
%APPDATA%\Code and
%USERPROFILE%.vscode

VSCODE then started as if newly installed.

I saw doing this as a last resort, but nothing has been lost from my vscode project.